# Print Function multi-dimensional Arrays when 2 different sizes exists C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having an issue creating a PRINT function that I will be able to run multiple times with different array sizes. I'll use this for an example.

Plane seating chart:

```
2 sections
-First Class
--5 rows 
--2 columns
---2 seats/column

-Coach Class
--5 rows
--2 columns
---3 seats/column
```

VISUAL:
[Example - Plane seating chart](http://i62.tinypic.com/34i44y1.jpg)

Question 1: How would I be able to print this out?

Question 2: How do I create a function to pass this through multiple times?

Problematic code (from a 2d perspective)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int COLS = 4;
const int ROW1 = 3, ROW2 = 4;

void showArray(const int [][COLS],int);

int main()
{
int table1 [ROW1][COLS] = {{1,2,3,},{6,7,8,9}};
int table2 [ROW2][COLS] = {{9,8,7,6},{5,4,3,2}};
cout << "Table 1 Array: \n" << endl;
showArray(table1,ROW1);
cout << "Table 2 Array: \n" << endl;
showArray(table2,ROW2);

return 0;
}
void showArray (const int array[][COLS], int rows)
{
for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < COLS; y++)
    {
        cout << setw(4) << array[x][y] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

The code above is an example of what I would need to do if the # of rows was needed to be determined....correct?

Now I know that code doesn't give me the correct print out because its placing 0's in empty spots which I know is do to y (or COLS) looping 4 times when there isn't a 4th value of x listed

Any ideas on how I can create a function that can be used multiple times with different array sizes and not give me 0's?

In this particular case, I can assign a CONST INT to the "Rows" because essentially they are 2 arrays of 5 but they would have different Y (columns) values if I counted each seat as new column.

Unless there is a way I can keep the same # of columns (2) and display multiple seats in each column that varies whether they are First Class or Coach Class.

Any ideas would be great.  I appreciate your guys help!

Comment: you should use std::vector instead of raw vectors

Comment: I haven't understood your goal... Do you want to print it out like the picture? Why do you use then an int array instead of an character array? What about a 3D array (column, row=2, and then the seat name `{'A', B'}` or `{'A', 'B', 'C'}` ...)? Maybe you should also use `vector` from std.

Comment: Ok, let me be the third... Use std::vector. It knows it's size. Using vector of vectors can give you not a square matrix

Comment: @borisbn for what i have understood, he need to write a function that will work with matrix of arbitrary dimension, rathen than work with square matrix

Comment: Do uninitialized array elements get initialized with 0? Then one could test for the first 0 in the array. Otherwise, no way, I'd say, as you cannot determine the last valid element in the array.

Answer (score 3):

Let me know if this is not what you ask. Here is an example on how you can print an arbitrary size multidimensional array. For this example i used `std::vector` as container. Please, take note that this is C++11 and it will not compile with C++98 (if you want to compile this code with a C++98 compiler you need to use iterators instead of range based for loop)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void show(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix)
{
    for(auto& vector : matrix) {
        for(auto& element : vector) {
            std::cout << element << " ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix1;

    matrix1.push_back({1,2,3});
    matrix1.push_back({4,5,6});
    matrix1.push_back({7,8,9});

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix2;

    matrix2.push_back({1,2,3,4,5});
    matrix2.push_back({6,7,8,9,10});

    std::cout << "Matrix1: " << std::endl;
    show(matrix1);

    std::cout << "Matrix2: " << std::endl;
    show(matrix2);
}
```

Comment: You've made the point implicitly, but it's worth to be pointed out: In C++, use `std::vector` instead of arrays unless you have a very good reason not to do it, as arrays create problems all the time (e.g., they do not know their size, so you always have to carry a second variable holding the size of the array).

Comment: Instead of the `push_back`s you can initialize the list in one step, I guess: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix1 { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };`